# Переработка jQuery в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток. Мне поставили задачу сделать так, чтоб активное поле меню выделялось. Я без проблем сделал это с помощью jQuery, но мне сказали, что из-за принципов нужно сделать это на javascript'e. И тут у меня возникла проблема. Код jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url=document.location.href;
    $.each($(".mainMenu a"),function(){
        if(this.href==url){$(this).addClass('activeClass');
            $("span",this).removeClass('bracket').addClass('activeClassBrackets');
        };
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
    <li><a href="/"><span class="bracket">[</span>Main<span class="bracket">]</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/1"><span class="bracket">[</span>1Page<span class="bracket">]</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="2"><span class="bracket">[</span>2Page<span class="bracket">]</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="3"><span class="bracket">[</span>3Page<span class="bracket">]</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.mainMenu a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').classList.add('activeClass');
document.querySelector('.mainMenu .activeClass span.bracket').classList.remove('bracket');
```

Comment: К сожелению, выдает вот такую ошыбку, _Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.mainMenu a[href=http://localhost:3000/3]' is not a valid selector_. Можно ли ее пофиксить как нибудь?

Comment: @ItsMyLife вам кто то дает задачи, а вы их делаете с помощью библиотеки, не зная основ чистого js? Как это возможно? Учитесь и разбирайтесь, задача элементарная. А все что будет в ней использоваться это `querySelectorAll('.mainMenu a')`, цикл по элементам и `el.classList.add('')` `el.classList.remove('')`

Comment: @ItsMyLife, поправил, в кавычки надо взять url. И не надо для этой задачи вообще циклы, но надо проверять существование элемента

Comment: забыл _activeClassBrackets_, к тому же со скобками неверное решение - их две, а ты только одну меняешь

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно, но я вообще удалил бы классы на span, все можно родительским классом делать

Comment: об этом стоило в ответе написать, а не просто кусок кода без объяснений кинуть

Comment: @Grundy, я бы так и сделал был бы в задаче полный кусок с css

Comment: а зачем тут css? В вопросе есть код и разметка к которой он применяется. Этого достаточно. Для того чтобы сказать, что вместо отдельно класса использовать вложенный - не нужен сам css, он ведь не поменяется

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev , спасибо большое. Но можно я еще кое что спрошу. В коде jquery есть  this.href который возвращает полные возможные ссылки перехода. А в чистов js'e a[href="'+window.location.href+'"] только то, что в параметре href="ЗДЕСЬ". Можно ли както добыть с помощью js'a так же как и с jquery?

Comment: @ItsMyLife, используй `pathname` вместо `href`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо огромное!, все. Конечный вариант вышел таким)  `document.querySelector('.mainMenu a[href="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').classList.add("activeClass");
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.mainMenu .activeClass span.bracket');
    for(i=0;i<el.length;i++) {
        el[i].classList.remove('bracket');
        el[i].classList.add('activeClassBrackets');
    }`